# Apriori Algorithm in Python using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, apriori

My dataset is shown in the image [image: Transactional dataset]

`My Code is:`

```
!pip install apyori
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from apyori import apriori

dataset = pd.read_csv('mydataset.csv')
records = len(dataset)
print(records)
dataset.head()

print(dataset.dtypes)
```

[image: dtypes]

```
transactions = []
for i in range(0, Total_Transections):
transactions.append([str(dataset.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 20)])

from apyori import apriori
Association_Rules = apriori(transactions, 
min_support = 0.008,
min_confidence = 0.2,
min_lift = 3,
min_length = 2)

Results = list(Rules)
print(len(Results))
print(Results)
```

It shows "0" Rules and "[ ]" Results. Rules and Results both are null.

How can i find the rules by using this dataset?

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

may be its too late now but i will suggest you to change min_lift value .Try min_lift=1 or min_lift =1.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).